# AutocompleteTextView with addresses

Tags: google-maps, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview, street-address

I have created simple Activity with AutcompleteTextView. I am trying to fetch addresses from input string using google geocode api. I get addresses in log but cant get them in the autocomplete view :/ What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView mListView;
    private Button mSearchButton;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container,
                false);

        mSearchButton = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_search_button);
        mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_search_list);
        mSearchView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_search_input);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                 mArrayAdapter.clear();
                 new FetchAutocompleteSuggestions().execute(buildSearchableUrl(s.toString()));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private String buildSearchableUrl(String insert){
        String result = "";
        insert = insert.replace(" ", "+");
        String intro = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
        String outro = "&sensor=true&components=country:sk";
        result = intro + insert + outro;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fragment_search_button:
            new FetchAutocompleteSuggestions().execute(buildSearchableUrl(mSearchView.getText().toString()));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private class FetchAutocompleteSuggestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayAdapter<String>>{

        private JSONParser jsonParser;


        @Override
        protected ArrayAdapter<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            String mPreparedUrl = params[0];
            JSONObject jobj = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(mPreparedUrl, null);
            Log.i("", mPreparedUrl);

            try{
                JSONArray array = jobj.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject childObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pom = childObject.getString("formatted_address");
                    Log.d("", pom);
                    mArrayAdapter.add(pom);
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(e.toString(), "Chyba");
            }           
            return mArrayAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter<String> result) {
            mSearchView.setAdapter(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I figured this out by setting up custom ArrayAdapter with Filter :) But I have still a bad problem. I am getting badly displayed chars from my Locale :/ from Log :

04-05 23:53:53.593: D/(13976): VysokoÅ¡kolÃ¡kov, Zilina, Slovakia
this should look like Vysokoškolákov, Žilina, Slovakia

Comment: Please give time to answering your own questions,if you do not know it rewards you points!